# Given the relational schema provide the queries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I started database in university a few weeks ago so I'm fairly new at this and the professor gave us these queries to solve as homework to be graded! I finished what I could but I'm not too certain if I did them correctly or not! I have posted some similar questions here before and received messages that tell me that this is the OLD way to write SQL but this is what the professor is asking so i beg you to ignore the way the queries are written! If you find something you think is wrong can you help me fix it?

Given the following relational schema:

- **TRAINER** (SSN, Name, Surname, City)
- **GYM** (CodG, NameP, City, Address)
- **SPECIALTY** (CodS, NameS, Description)
- **GROUP_LESSON** (SSN, CodG, Date, CodS, ParticipantsNumber)

Write the following queries in SQL language:

1. Show SSN, name and surname of every personal trainer who gave group lessons in
   at least 3 dierent gyms located in Turin.

   ```
    SELECT T.SSN, NAME, SURNAME
    FROM TRAINER T
    WHERE SSN IN (SELECT SSN
                  FROM GROUP_LESSONS GL, GYM G
                  WHERE G.CITY = 'TURIN' AND G.CODG = GL.CODG
                  GROUP BY SSN
                  HAVING COUNT(SSN) >= 3)
   ```
2. For each gym in which more than 10 Karate group lessons (NameS = "Karate") have been conducted, show the code of the gym and, separately for each trainer, the total number of participants to the group lessons (of any specialty) given by the trainer in that gym.

   ```
    SELECT 
        g.CODG, t.SSN, t.Name, T.surname, t.City, SUM(gl.ParticipantsNumber)
    FROM  
        (SELECT gl.CodG
         FROM GROUP_LESSON GL, SPECIALITY S
         WHERE S.CODS = GL.CODS AND S.NAMES = 'KARATE'
         GROUP BY GL.CODG
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 10) AS G, GROUP_LESSON GL, TRAINER T
    WHERE GL.CODG = G.CODG AND T.SSN = GL.SSN
    GROUP BY G.CODG, T.SSN, T.NAME, T.SURNAME, T.CITY
   ```
3. For each personal trainer who gave group lessons at every gym in his city, show name, surname and the number of specialties for which he gave lessons.

   ```
     SELECT NAME, SURNAME, COUNT(*)
     FROM TRAINER T, SPECIALTIES S, GROUP_LESSONS GL
     WHERE T.SSN = GL.SSN AND GL.CODS = S.CODS
     GROUP BY T.CITY
     HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.CITY)
                        FROM GYM G, TRAINER T1, GROUP_LESSONS GL1
                        WHERE T1.SSN = GL1.SSN AND G.COG = GL1.CODG 
                          AND T1.CITY = G.CITY
                        GROUP BY T1.CITY)
   ```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: People said that to me in some previous questions i posted here! But as i said the my professor at the moment taught us this way of writing them and he wants the answer written this way! I dont have a choice here im sorry!

Comment: I hope your professor didn't also tell you to code with caps lock on :)

Answer (score 0):

What's old about this? In ANSI SQL 1992 it became possible to write

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM TRAINER T1
  JOIN GROUP_LESSONS GL1 ON T1.SSN = GL1.SSN
  JOIN GYM G ON G.CODG = G1.CODG AND G.CITY = G.CITY
 WHERE whatever
GROUP BY whatever
```

Using JOIN ... ON in place of the comma-join syntax has a couple of benefits.

1. It separates the specification of relationships between tables from the specification of filtering. The relationships are expressed in ON-clauses and the filters in WHERE-clauses.
2. It allows the expression of outer join operations like LEFT JOIN using a standardized syntax.

With respect for your professor, may I suggest she read a few recent books on relational data engineering? Or, if not that, retire? This JOIN stuff was standardized 29 years ago. You'll have trouble in the world of working programming if you use the old comma join stuff.

I guess you can use this as university course as an opportunity to learn the difficult, obscure, and old way of doing things.

** EDIT **   That last question is complex!  I believe the first line of your last query should be

```
    SELECT T.NAME, T.SURNAME, COUNT(DISTINCT GL.CODS)
```

because you want the number of distinct specialities, not the number of lessons taught.   Also, you don't need to access the SPECIALITIES table here, because you can get the `CODS` value from the GROUP_LESSONS table.

Please keep in mind that the only thing worse than learning obsolete stuff is blindly copying and pasting code from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! As for why i wrote things this way i guess we are supposed to write in oracle 11g i think and there are some "solutions" to some of the problems and they are written like this! I will try to change it because it doesnt seem that difficult but i have some examples in the slides here that they write it like this! If possible can i confirm just for the last exercise if its correct or you think its correct or not? Thats the one im more worried about! Thanks

Comment: Oracle discontinued support for 11g on  Jan 1, 2021, for what it's worth. Your university's curriculum is *obsolete.* That might be OK for medieval history but certainly not for engineering.

Comment: XD! well now thats just embarasing ! Honestly if what you say its true i dont know if i should laugh or cry! Thanks. again! Can i ask you to check part c because thats the one im more worried about

Comment: Looking at it now.  It is a complex problem.